# How to install .deb file?

Tags: files, deb

Hi just started in Ubuntu and can't install any program from Ubuntu Software I read some solutions and need to install gdebi , I download the package installer.deb but still can't install gdebi , please help me how to install gdebi

Note : i dont have internet access , need to install gdebi before access to the internet

Comment: sudo dpkg -i gdebixxxxxxx.deb

Comment: Error processing

Answer (score 3):

***WITHOUT INTERNET***

You can install it using

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`

followed by

`sudo apt-get install -f`

***WITH INTERNET ACCESS***

install **Gdebi**

in terminal enter

`sudo apt-get install gdebi`

after install completes go to the .deb file in file explorer-->right click-->open with--->select gdebi--->once gdebi opens and loads select "install package"

Comment: Didn't you see the last line: "Note : i dont have internet access , need to install gdebi before access to the internet" ?

Comment: This would require internet access, which he stated he doesn't have.

Comment: oh....I completely missed the last line...Then this should work:-

Comment: using  
 sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file 
 followed by   sudo apt-get install -f.

Comment: Yeah I need to install gdebi and then install my WiFi driver because Ubuntu software won't let me install any .deb file